# Vk_api не работает в чем дело?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

В общем, учусь писать ботов для ВК на `Python`'e. В языке новичок.

Столкнулся с ошибкой и не знаю, куда двигаться.

**Вот код:**

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from datetime import datetime
import random
import data

token = "***"

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, 194510981)
vk = vk.get_api()

while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if event.object.peer_id != event.object.from_id:
                responsive = event.object.text.lower()
                if responsive == 'hi':
                    vk.messages.send(peer_id=event.object.peer_id , message='Hello world', random_id=0)
                if responsive == '/история':
                    max_message = vk.messages.getHistory(peer_id=event.object.peer_id)['count']
                    text = []
                    for i in range(0,max_message,200):
                        mess = vk.messages.getHistory(peer_id=event.object.peer_id, count=200,offset=i)['items']
                        for element in mess:
                            if element.get('action') == None:
                                text.append(str(element['id']))
                    text = ','.join(text)
                    print(text)
```

**Вот ошибка:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 21, in <module>
    max_message = vk.messages.getHistory(peer_id=event.object.peer_id)['count']
  File "C:\Users\linkq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 681, in __call__
    return self._vk.method(self._method, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\linkq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 646, in method
    raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [15] Access denied
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, версию `Long Poll` (посмотреть можно на одноимённой вкладке в настройках сообщества). Привести её в вопрос Вы можете, нажав кнопку [edit]. Так будет легче Вам помочь.

Comment: версия LongPoll 5.102 разрешение на чат тоже выданны

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял это попытка получить историю сообщений в чате, у ботов даже нет id сообщений в беседах, следовательно получить историю невозможно. То что тут https://vk.com/dev/messages.getHistory написано, что "этот метод можно вызвать с ключом доступа сообщества" - бред, будет доступен после введения айдишников для ботов.

Comment: что мне делать ? Посоветуйте пожалуйста

Comment: Доставать историю не получится, зачем бот её вообще достает? Возможно можно как то еще реализовать.

Comment: Лучше будет если сделать бота со страницы пользователся да ?

Comment: Да можно и так, с токеном пользователя историю доставать можно, но тогда будут другие неприятности вроде капчи.

Comment: А через сообщество вообше не как нельзя да ? А если через пользователя то как избегать капчи ?

Comment: Через сообщество можно будет только когда разработчики вк добавят айди у сообщений для ботов, что они обещают уже год. Избегать капчи можно с помощью рукапчи, стоит довольно дешево - [python-rucaptcha](https://github.com/AndreiDrang/python-rucaptcha)

Comment: Спасибо попробую, кстати а вы случайно не знаете как закреплять сообщение в беседе ботом я хотел реализовать через получения масива истрии и закрепить последнего сообщение

Comment: Вот так https://vk.com/dev/messages.pin

Comment: да через messages pin хочу но не знаю как это реализовывается